# How to Search Text in CSV File and Print to New CSV File

Tags: python, csv

Sort of stuck trying to figure this out. I'm trying to search for specific text within a CSV file that has thousands of lines of code. Once I find the text I'm looking for, I'm trying to print out the text as a header into a new CSV file. The caveat is that there is no header in the CSV file I'm searching in and the text I'm searching for is throughout the entire file.

**Example: CSV File**

Revision: ABC

Model: DEF

Type: GHI

**Pseudocode:**

Trying to search for Revision:

Print Revision: on first row [0:0]

Print ABC underneath Revision [1:0]

Print Model: on the first row, second column [0:1]

Print DEF underneath Model [1:1]

**What I currently have:**

```
import csv, re, pandas as pd

from csv import reader

with open('Example.csv', 'r') as file:
    csv_reader = reader(file)
    
    for row in csv_reader:
        for header in row:
            if header == str('Revision: ')
            print(header.split(': ')
```

Comment: How does "what you currently have" compare with what you want?  That is, what are you *specifically* asking for help with?

Comment: That doesn't look like a csv (columnar data). It looks like key/value pairs separated by a colon. And the output isn't csv either. Is the pattern in this file always the same... a Revision followed by Model and unnamed other stuff you don't care about? Are there empty lines in there?

Comment: you are using wrong paradigm. CSV - comma separated values.  Looks like you have text file of key/value pairs.  Construct a dict from it then print. `text = '''Revision: ABC
Model: DEF
Type: GHI'''
d = {row.split(":")[0]:row.split(":")[1] for row in text.split("\n")}
print(pd.DataFrame([d]).to_string(index=False))`

Answer (score 0):

`itertools.groupby` can help parse the input file by creating a new line iterator each time "Revision:" is seen. It returns a boolean telling you whether a condition has been met, and an iterator for all lines until the condition changes. So, you get `True` and an iterator for 1 line when "Revision:" is seen, and then another iterator for all of the lines until "Revision:" is seen again.

Assuming your input file looks like this (call it "data.txt")

```
Revision: ABC
Model: DEF
Type: GHI
Revision: 111 
Model: 222
Type: 333
```

This script will convert it to a csv

```
import itertools
import csv

def is_rev(line):
    return line.startswith("Revision:")

with open("data.txt") as infp, open("data.csv", "w", newline="") as outfp:
    writer = csv.writer(outfp)
    writer.writerow(["Revision", "Model"])
    for newrev, lines in itertools.groupby(infp, is_rev):
        if newrev:
            revision = next(lines).split(":", 1)[1].strip()
        else:
            for line in lines:
                if line.startswith("Model:"):
                    model = line.split(":", 1)[1].strip()
                    writer.writerow([revision, model])
                    break
```

Output csv

```
Revision,Model
ABC,DEF
111,222
```

Comment: Can you please explain what:      with open("data.txt") as infp is?

Comment: @smithbryanw - Its the name I gave to the example input data file. Since that's not CSV format, I just called it "txt". `with open("data.txt") as infp`  opens the file and calls the file object "infp". The `with` means that the file will automatically close when the "with" clause (suite) ends.

Comment: I apologize, i'm extremely new to python. The file that i'm reading from is CSV format. Why would I need to have "with open("data.txt")"?

Answer (score 0):

As I've understood your question you have the file with lines of the following format `<key>:<value>` and you want to get the CSV first raw of which is the keys and second is the values. In that case, you can do something like this

```py
import pandas as pd
# sep stands for separator, the default is a comma, if values are separated with colon we
# have to specify it
# header paramener is the number of row that should be used as header, setting it to None
# means that there isn't header in file
df = pd.read_csv("Example.csv", sep=":", header=None)
df[0].apply(lambda x: x.strip()) # removes leading space
df = df.transpose()
# index is set to false so as not to write the row names to the file
df.to_csv("Result.csv", index=False)
```

Comment: I tried using your code, but i'm getting an error on line: df[0].apply(lambda x: x.strip())

Comment: I have got a mistake on that line it should be `df[1] = df[1].apply(lambda x: x.strip())` otherwise it won't have any effect, although I don't understand why you are getting an error because when I run the code on my machine it works without throwing errors, just doesn't remove leading whitespace before values

Comment: I apologize. I'm extremely new to python. I seem to be getting this error:             (base) c:\Users\M71158\Python Code>python Bryan_Practice_Read_Write_CSV.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Bryan_Practice_Read_Write_CSV.py", line 35, in <module>
    df = pd.read_csv("Example.csv", sep=":", header=None)
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 685, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 463, in _read

Comment: pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 5, saw 2

Answer (score 0):

I think you can handle it with something tricky like:
Example.csv:

```
Revision: ABC
Model: DEF
Type: GHI
Revision: 111
Model: 222
Type: 333
Revision: A11
Model: B22
Type: C33
```

read_csv

```
df=pd.read_csv('Example.csv', sep=': ', names=['key', 'value']) 
df['nb'] =df.index.values.tolist()
```

df:

```
        key value  nb
0  Revision   ABC   0
1     Model   DEF   1
2      Type   GHI   2
3  Revision   111   3
4     Model   222   4
5      Type   333   5
6  Revision   A11   6
7     Model   B22   7
8      Type   C33   8

pivot_table = df.pivot_table(index=['nb'],
                     columns=['key'],
                     values=['value'],
                     aggfunc=lambda x: ''.join(str(v) for v in x)).fillna(method='bfill').dropna()
```

df=pivot_table.iloc[::3]

df:

```
key Model Revision Type
nb
0     DEF      ABC  GHI
3     222      111  333
6     B22      A11  C33
```

You can finally recorder columns with:

```
df = df[["Revision", "Model", "Type"]]
```

Comment: Hello @Renaud. Can you please explain your code? I tried copying and pasting the best I could, but I keep getting an indent error for the data frame: key value nb. Also, The value will change everytime I open a new CSV file. So how would I go about printing that out?